# PHP - Including class an put inside class variable

Tags: php, class, variables, public

I have written this syntax inside a class in my php code

```
public static function cmp_header() {
    ?>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="upside">
            <div class="upside-layout layout">
                <div class="title">
                    <span class="logo">
                        <img src="<?php echo me_url ?>images/websites/logo-meapp.png" alt="">
                    </span>
                    <span class="label">MeApp</span>
                </div>
                <div class="navigation">
                    <div class="navigation-layout layout">
                        <?php
                            if($this->config->something()) {
                                ?>
                                <div class="masuk no-events menu" atr="redirect/masuk">
                                    <div class="masuk click-events header-button menu" atr="redirect|daftar">Welcome, Irvan Hilmi</div>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                            } else {
                                ?>
                                <div class="masuk no-events menu" atr="redirect/masuk">
                                    <div class="masuk click-events header-button menu" atr="redirect|daftar">Daftar</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="masuk no-events menu" atr="redirect/masuk">
                                    <div class="masuk click-events header-button menu" atr="redirect|masuk">Masuk</div>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                            }
                        ?>
                        <div class="# no-events menu" atr="do/toggle-more-menu">
                            <div class="# click-events header-button menu" atr="do|toggle-more-menu">#</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
public function __construct() {
    require_once('config.php');
    $this->config = new config();
}
```

The `config.php` file, has a class named `config`, i'm already put the variable `$config` as `public`. declared with `public $config` inside the class.

But the problem is, when i try to access the variable `$config`, with statement `$this->config` and call a method inside `config` class, like `$this->config->something();` it some an error like this.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context

Also i already make sure that the class and the method inside `config.php` are at `public` scope.

Here the `config.php` file

```
class config {
    public function something() {
        // the method script here
    }
    public function __construct() {
        // nothing just yet
    }
}
```

Is there any possible why to do this? to make a class stored on variable inside a class like `public $config`?

Thanks for any correction and suggestion.

Comment: Can you please edit the question and show how code inside `config.php` looks like instead of just describing it?

Comment: Where and how are you trying to access the `config` property exactly, what does the code look like and what is its context? You need to post the code around the line that is causing the error.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález sure things

Comment: You cannot create classes in arbitrary places, let alone a class method. That's how PHP syntax works (it isn't actually related to `include`).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález what that supposed to be mean? sorry i'm new learner, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
public static function cmp_header() {
```

This is a static method, so inside this method there is no `$this` as you can call it using just the class name and not call it on a specific object.

Note that when you solve this, you will run into another problem and that is that you cannot nest class declarations. You should include the class at the top of the file or - better - use autoloading to load the classes you need.

Comment: you mean, i need to write `public function cmp_header()` instead of `public static cmp_header()` ?

Comment: @IrvanHilmi That would depend on how you call it. Also note my edit, after solving this you will run into the next problem.

Comment: i already update the code and write the method like this `public static cmp_header()` and call it using this line of script `$this->config->something();` but still got the same error. Can i call it in the other way?

Comment: Cause i do some other thing, include a file that has a class, and call it only using `$sampleClass = new sampleClass()` and work fine, but when i try to store the `$sampleClass `at class variable, inside the class that include the file, like `public $sampleClass;` and assign the class `$this->sampleClass = new sampleClass()`, and i want to call the method iside `$this->sampleClass` like `$this->sampleClass->someMethod();` but got that error, sorry if i make you confuse. I really didn't understand what a i'm getting right now

Comment: You rigth, i'm facing more problem when i solved it, but i already fix it and get what i want using autoload stuff, i tried `spl_autoload()` and it work well.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create classes in arbitrary places. For instance, you can do e.g. [this](https://3v4l.org/ACUjT):

```
class A{}

function create_b()
{
    class B{}  
}
```

... but not e.g. [this](https://3v4l.org/sEUB0):

```
class A
{
    public function foo()
    {
        class B{}
    }
}
// Fatal error: Class declarations may not be nested
```

That's how the language works.

In your case, though, I suspect you aren't even trying to nest classes. Move the `include` statement to the top of the file (or, even better, implement class auto-loading) and this will be solved.

Last but not least, `cmp_header()` cannot be static and access instance properties at the same time. Either make it a regular method or change the design altogether and pass `config` as param:

```
public static function cmp_header(config $config) {
    if($config->something()) {
```